# ROS2 Talker cannot communicate with Listener

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use ROS2.

I finished to setup ROS2,but talker cannot communicate with listener.

My setup is below.

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl 
$ curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install `apt list "ros-ardent-*" 2> /dev/null | grep "/" | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | grep -v -e ros-ardent-ros1-bridge -e ros-ardent-turtlebot2- | tr "\n" " "`
```

So, the terminal 1 is

```
$ source /opt/ros/ardent/setup.bash
$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

and, the terminal 2 is

```
$ source /opt/ros/ardent/setup.bash
$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
```

terminal 1 display

```
$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[INFO] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
[INFO] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 4'
[INFO] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 5'
```

but ,terminal 2 no response.

What am I wrong?

(I use Ubuntu16.04LTS)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300370/ros2-talker-cannot-communicate-with-listener/) by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2018-08-12

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-09-10**:
How long have you left the listener running for to wait for a response? Discovery can take some time, although on a local machine I would expect it to success fairly quickly.

**Comment by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on 2018-09-10**:
I waited for about ten seconds,but not try it more.
After a change of my ufw, I could success quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you are allowing [multicast traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) in the firewall. By default, the `ufw` firewall included in 16.04 blocks multicast traffic, even for loopback (i.e. on the same system). [Here's an example of allowing multicast in `ufw`](https://einar.slaskete.net/2014/05/03/allow-multicast-and-igmp-with-ufw-for-iptv-to-work/).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on 2018-08-13**:
I can communicate with listener by the the way of above site.

I allow udp multicast in ufw.

```
sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 224.0.0.0/4
sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 224.0.0.0/4
```

Thank you for your help!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-09-10**:
If you run into a similar problem you can try the new `multicast` verb to test if simple multicast functionality is working for you: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/pull/145

**Comment by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) on 2019-09-25**:
Also note, the same symptoms (i.e. ROS2 Talker cannot communicate with Listener) occur if the computer has no network configured. To test, try this:
`ros2 multicast receive` in one terminal and `ros2 multicast send` in another terminal.
If there are errors like `load_entry_point …` then plug your computer into a network and try again.

**Comment by [codierknecht](https://answers.ros.org/users/25842/codierknecht/) on 2021-08-23**:
Is there someone else with ros2 multicast working, other nodes are not able to see each other? Even `ros2 topic pub /chatter std_msgs/String "data: ping"` in one terminal isn't noticed by `ros2 topic list` in an another terminal. Of cause both have ros2 galactic sourced.

**Comment by [twaddell](https://answers.ros.org/users/84822/twaddell/) on 2021-09-27**:
@codierknecht, I also have that issue, what version are you running? did you ever find a fix?

**Comment by [codierknecht](https://answers.ros.org/users/25842/codierknecht/) on 2021-10-01**:
@twaddell I did mange to solve the problem for running nodes on the same machine by exporting ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1. However I currently don't have a second machine due to cross-compilation problems for a raspberry pi model 2b.

**Comment by [RickROS2](https://answers.ros.org/users/133941/rickros2/) on 2023-01-12**:
I have a similar problem. I am trying to connect a raspberry pi 3B+ to my pc with ROS2. I can connect to it just fine, my firewall is not active and multicast/ping between them works. However, topics listed on my pi do not show up on my pc and talker listener mode does not work either. (listener no response). ROS_ID is both 30. Please help me I do not know what else to do.

**Comment by [grhex](https://answers.ros.org/users/144164/grhex/) on 2023-04-03**:
I have a similar problem with ROS2 humble. I tried several things, including:
sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 224.0.0.0/4
sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 224.0.0.0/4
"ros2 multicast receive" and "ros2 multicast send" communicated between two machines over wifi, but the talker and listener still didn't.

**Comment by [xaxam2001](https://answers.ros.org/users/149288/xaxam2001/) on 2023-05-16**:
Hi, I have the exact same issue that @grhex. I'm trying to use a turtlebot4 that use a pi 4B. I can ping the pi from my machine and the machine from my pi, `ros2 multicast receive` and `ros2 multicast send` are working fine. But the listener and the talker doesn't communicate, I **can't** use `ros2 node list`, I **can't** stop the daemon using `ros2 daemon stop` and I think there are a lot of other commands I can't use. Even after adding the rules in the answer above and even if I disable the ufw firewall.

I precise that I'm using Discovery Server configuration and I'm using FastDDS.

Does someone have any solution now ?